What is the meaning of the creature in the Titan's eye?
In the final episode of The Owl House, when Luz sees

 the spirit of the Titan that was King's parent,

one of their eyes has a long worm-like creature sticking out of it, which bears a distinct resemblance to the alleged house demon Hooty.
What is the connection between this creature and Hooty?
